# resize2fs does not resize filesystem

Tags: linux, storage

I'm mounting a volume from a storage array on an Centos 6.5 server. I resized the volume and tried to resize the FS on the server, but resize2fs does not resize.

I'm not using LVM. I'm mounting /dev/mapper device directly on the mount point with an entry in /etc/fstab.

Note that I downloaded and built e2fsprogs-1.43.5 to elimininate the possibility of bugs in the version that came with centos 6.5. Used the built mke2fs & resize2fs.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

```
- On storage array: Created 1TB volume
Name         Size  Source  Created                  Serial
test-resize  1T    -       2017-08-05 20:52:47 MDT  8A6E42D13A7D45AE00011014

- On server: rescan found multiple devices for the volume
[root@init105-12 hariharan]# rescan-scsi-bus.sh
...
4 new or changed device(s) found.
        [7:0:0:2]
        [8:0:0:2]
        [9:0:0:2]
        [10:0:0:2]

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# ll /dev/mapper
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Aug  5 20:52 3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae00011010 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Aug  5 20:53 3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae00011014 -> ../dm-3     <--- new volume
crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 58 Aug  3 17:50 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Aug  3 17:50 vgroot-lvroot -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Aug  3 17:50 vgroot-lvswap01 -> ../dm-0

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# service multipathd reload
Reloading multipathd:                                      [  OK  ]

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# mke2fs -t ext4 -O 'has_journal,ext_attr,resize_inode,dir_index,filetype,extent,flex_bg,sparse_super,huge_file,uninit_bg,dir_nlink,extra_isize,large_file' /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae00011014

- On storage array: Resized volume to 2TB
Name         Size  Source  Created                  Serial
test-resize  2T    -       2017-08-05 20:52:47 MDT  8A6E42D13A7D45AE00011014

- On server
[root@init105-12 hariharan]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae00011014
resize2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
The filesystem is already 268435456 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

- Try rescan & multipathd restart - did not help

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# rescan-scsi-bus.sh
...
0 new or changed device(s) found.
0 remapped or resized device(s) found.

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# service multipathd reload
Reloading multipathd:                                      [  OK  ]

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae00011014
resize2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
The filesystem is already 268435456 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk`. As a side note: when creating a filesystem, it is better to **not** specify all filesystem options, rather only the required ones (which differ from default).

Comment: Really bad idea to use compiled mkfs and resize2fs. While it shouldn't happen, they could be incompatible with the kernel driver for that FS.

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie Know it's a bad idea, but that was a last resort since whatever came with centos 6.5 did not work.

Comment: @shodanshok, here's the lsblk output. The resize just worked for me, but when I tried it again it didn't. Looks like you get the right sequence of things. Will have to find it.

[root@init105-12 hariharan]# lsblk /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101a
NAME                                     MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101a (dm-2) 253:2    0   1T  0 mpath

Comment: This is quite flaky. Did this after resizing volume (did not create filesystem because the problem is with the server finding the new size of the block device). _rescan-scsi-bus.sh -r -i; service multipathd reload; ll /dev/mapper/; lsblk /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101b_. lsblk reported 1TB. When I tried lsblk a few seconds later without doing anything else, it reported 2TB.

Comment: Please always add additional information to the question itself, so it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence seems to produce consistent results. (NOTE: When I was trying this test, I'm pretty sure I was able to run rescan-scsi-bus.sh without any arguments to find new volumes on the storage.array. Now I have to specify *-i* to find new volumes. rescan does not find the new volume without it. Server and array are connected via fibre channel.)

I used the same sequence of commands after creating the volume and after resizing.

```
rescan-scsi-bus.sh -r -i
sleep 5
service multipathd reload
ll /dev/mapper/
sleep 5
lsblk /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101f

Resize works:
[root@init105-12 hariharan]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101e
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101e to 536870912 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101e is now 536870912 blocks long.
```